# How to create a login to a SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, wix

I have made a bootstrapper-project with WiX 3.8.
As a prerequisite SQL Server Express 2012 is installed, setting "SQLExpress" as name of the new SQL Server instance.
Then in the MSI i want to create a new SQL user login.
I tried this with the User-element, but it doesn't seem to work.
When i take a look to the logins in the SQL Server Management tool, i can't see my new user, but the log from my MSI tells me, that he was created.

Is there something wrong with my version of the User-element or have i to take another way?

```
<Component Id ="CreateUserAccount"
           Guid="AEE91491-99FA-40A9-AB47-1E9FC2DDEF2A"
           Directory="TARGETDIR">
    <util:User Id ="SQLUser"
               Name="[DBUSER_PROP]"
               Password="[DBPW_PROP]"
               UpdateIfExists="no"
               CreateUser="yes"
               PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
               PasswordExpired="no"
               RemoveOnUninstall="no"
               Domain="[ComputerName]">
    </util:User>
</Component>
```

Comment: Where are you creating a SQL level password? That looks like a windows user to me - unless you generate a login at the db level or ad it to a group with login rights, it is totally not relevant for sql at all.

Comment: Seems like you're specifying a computer account with this Domain="[ComputerName]". If you don't have this user on your computer, it won't work. Also, specifying a GUID (sid) might be the reason why it's not added should it be already taken. Finally, did you try to refresh the Security folder?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Phill Hogland from Windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset i have found the solution.
It depends on the language used on the PC.
In my case that's german, which means, the group Users cannot be found by the name "Users" but "Benutzer".

Here the correct code:

```
<util:Group Id="Users"
            Name ="Benutzer"
            Domain="[ComputerName]" />
<Component Id ="CreateUserAccount"
           Guid="AEE91491-99FA-40A9-AB47-1E9FC2DDEF2A"
           Directory="TARGETDIR">
    <util:User Id ="SQLUser"
               Name="[DBUSER_PROP]"
               Password="[DBPW_PROP]"
               UpdateIfExists="no"
               CreateUser="yes"
               PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
               PasswordExpired="no"
               RemoveOnUninstall="no">
        <util:GroupRef Id ="Users" />
    </util:User>
</Component>
```

Further You can replace the hardcoded name by a bundle-variable.
Then You will be independent from the OS language.