# Wix Toolset: Create SQL Login

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm working on an installer based on wix 3.9 which deploys a database along with other needed files. The installer must also add a Login to the SQL Server with sysadmin rights.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485733/how-to-create-a-login-to-a-sql-server-instance) thread with this code but I think that a local user is being created and definitely not an Login on my sql instance and unfortunately due to permissions I can't even access the CP to check for that. Any ideas would be helpful since I can't find any documentation on the issue.

```
<util:Group Id="Users"
        Name ="Benutzer"
        Domain="[ComputerName]" />
 <Component Id ="CreateUserAccount"
       Guid="AEE91491-99FA-40A9-AB47-1E9FC2DDEF2A"
       Directory="TARGETDIR">
<util:User Id ="SQLUser"
           Name="[DBUSER_PROP]"
           Password="[DBPW_PROP]"
           UpdateIfExists="no"
           CreateUser="yes"
           PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
           PasswordExpired="no"
           RemoveOnUninstall="no">
    <util:GroupRef Id ="Users" />
</util:User>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` creates Windows users. If you want to create a SQL login, use `SqlString` or `SqlScript` to run a [`CREATE LOGIN` query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out easier than I thought

```
<sql:SqlString Id="sql_us" ExecuteOnInstall="yes"  SQL="CREATE LOGIN SQL_USER WITH PASSWORD = 'password', DEFAULT_DATABASE=&quot;master&quot; , CHECK_POLICY= OFF;" Sequence="6"/>​
```